# Deleting pattern from file using vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to delete pattern from a file.

```
Edge[15] = 415 
Edge[16] = 65 
Edge[17] = 835 
Edge[18] = 951 
Edge[19] = 999 
Edge[20] = 887 ...
```

How to delete everything before Numbers i.e till = , i.e i want just numbers and then wants to join using ,.

`[415,65,835,...]`

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Comment: Oh forgot about the post ... I can search for .*= and replace it with =  /=... i.e delete all things till = . and then do the same and replace it with empty. then add using regular expression at end of line , and then %j . I wanted was a one liner . If possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so you're asked for a one-liner instead of the multiple steps you've given. There surely are many other ways, here's one:

```
:%s/.*=\s*\(\d\+\)\n/\1, / | normal! $xr]^OI[
```

This does the removal of the stuff before `=` and the *joining* of lines both with `:substitute` (adapt the `:%` range to suit your needs), by capturing only the number. I then use normal mode commands to get rid of the trailing comma and add the square brackets. (Type `^O` as Ctrl-V Ctrl-O; Ctrl-Q CTRL-O on Windows.) If you have the *surround.vim* plugin, this could be further simplified. One could also use a second `:.substitute` to achieve the same.

Actually, I probably would have used visual blockwise mode, a special `J` mapping, and normal mode to achieve this.

Comment: oh.. Need some time to digest it. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget the excellent built-in `:help`; you'll learn tons from it!

Comment: Okay. Have just started to use vim hence little slow in catching. But surely will become dangerous in few weeks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use two regex

```
:%s/.*\( \d\+\).*\n/\1,/g

:%s/^ \(.*\),.\{-}$/[\1]
```

**Output:**

```
[415, 65, 835, 951, 999, 887]
```